# Spring boot rest end point on AWS working locally but not when deployed to AWS Elastic bean stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a Spring restful application and it is working fine locally and is connecting to `AWS RDS Postgressql`. When deploying the same jar to `AWS Elastic Bean Stack(AWS ESB)` using the upload button I can see the following error in the log and getting **502 Bad Gateway** in the browser. `AWS RDS Postgresql` is not configured from *AWS ESB*, but from *RDS* dashboard.

I have set `SERVER_PORT`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_KEY` and others related to DB as the environmental variables in the AWS ESB configuration page.

I can see that a a simple spring application is working when deployed to AWS ESB, but not when the kind described above with AWS RDS post gres sql.

> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:235)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]   at
>   com.app.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:18) [classes!/:na]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [application.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [application.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [application.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [application.jar:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed;
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:235) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
>       at com.app.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:18) [classes!/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [application.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [application.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [application.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [application.jar:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/cache/config/annotation/ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cachingConfigurer' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:88) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:248) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 22 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/cache/config/annotation/ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cachingConfigurer' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:88) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:248) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 43 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/cache/config/annotation/ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cachingConfigurer' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1275) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1180) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 69 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 85 common frames omitted

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Following was the initial dependency in the build.gradle file when the above described error  was coming.

compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.1.Final'
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.0.0'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-jdbc'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.122'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:1.11.123'
```

After removing last 2 dependencies the build is successfully getting executed in AWS EBS.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by removing 2 dependencies, which I tracked from ElastiCacheCachingConfiguration:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws', version: '2.2.3.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging', version: '2.2.3.RELEASE'
```

I still have

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.122'
```

for the AWS API.